# Domain of a map in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Is it possible to write a function that returns the domain of a map which is defined as follows:

```
Variable A B : Type. 
Hypothesis A_eqB_dec : forall x y : A, {x = y} + {x <> y}.

Definition map := A -> option B.
```

Comment: yes,  const None, i.e the function that always returns None, but I assume you are looking for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you call the domain. If it is a proposition of elements of `A`, then that function is easy to define:

```
Definition domain_prop (A B : Type) (map : A -> option B) : A -> Prop :=
  exists (b : B), map a = Some b
```

You can even make this better, by replacing the proposition by a boolean, since "not being `None`" is decidable:

```
Definition domain_bool (A B : Type) (map : A -> option B) : A -> bool :=
  fun a => match (map a) with | None => false | Some _ => true end
```

Note that defining these does not require any properties on `A` or `B`. However, if you want to *enumerate* elements of the domain in some form, then I do not think you can do that without assuming that `A` is enumerable in some way. If `A` is enumerable, you should be able to enumerate elements in the domain as well, by going through `A` and selecting only elements which are in the domain (in the sense of `domain_bool` above). The exact way to do this will depend on your definition of "enumerable".